# Regexp returns blank when only containing letters

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have a regex expression

```
  ^[0-9]{6}[A-Zööö|0-9]{1}[0-9]{3}$
```

when the first characters are letters the field becomes empty.

I want it the preserve the letters. The following is the form validation code I use:

```
  if (!searchForm.getPersonnummer().equalsIgnoreCase("")  && !LPWFormatValidator.validSSNFormat(pnr)) {
  bindingResult.rejectValue("personnummer", "tg02.pnrFormat", "tg02.pnrFormat");
}
```

How do I keep the "wrong text" in the form field, but signal the error to the user?

Comment: Your expression currently says "the first six characters must be digits" `^[0-9]{6}` - which is why you get empty. Can you show an example of what you want certain strings to become? `abc -> abc; 123abc -> ''; 123456abc -> 123456` or whatever...

Comment: There are some unusual characters in your regex you've posted ("A-Zööö|")...

Comment: The expression controls that contains a social security number on the form 4312253332, but when the user inputs only letters the field blanks out, i want a message that it is wrong and the letters to remain.

Comment: The letters are unusual because it is Swedish.

Comment: It sounds like this is not a question about regex, but about form validation then? Your "special characters" all render as the same "o with umlaut" three times; and there is a `|` which is interpreted as the literal character `|` when I suspect you think you are writing "or"...

Comment: I have  public static boolean validSSNFormat(String pnr) {
   if (pnr.matches(here I want a regex that controls if the first letters not digits, but letters){
   else 
   return pnr.matches(RGX_PNR);

public static final String RGX_PNR = "^[0-9]{6}[A-Zööö|0-9]{1}[0-9]{3}$";
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
^[0-9]{6}
```

states that your String needs to start with six digits and only then letters may be expected.
Make the first part optional, if you need to be able to grab letters.

Comment: how do i make it optional

Comment: If you want to have no numbers or 6 digits (instead of e.g. any amount of and up to 6 digits), Floris suggestion will solve your problem: ^(\d{6})?

Answer (score 0):

If you want "either 6 digits, or none" at the start of your expression, then you modify the expression to

```
^([0-9]{6})?[A-Zööö|0-9]{1}[0-9]{3}$
```

Wrapping the "six digits" into `()?` means "zero or one times". As it stands, your expression means the following:

```
^[0-9]{6}        string must start (^) with exactly 6 digits
[A-Zööö|0-9]{1}  exactly one character from A-Z, ööö| , or digit from 0-9
[0-9]{3}         three digits
$                and nothing more ("end of string")
```

Thus, as it stands your regex will match things like

```
123456A123
999999|000
```

But not

```
The number you want is 123456xC123 but you're not getting it
```

You need to explain more clearly what other strings should be matched / "preserved" / captured...